# Error in Preparing your Environment: The system cannot find the path

Tags: node.js, api, command-prompt, spotify

I am trying to start my first API with Spotify.

I am using [this site](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/#disqus_thread) for my walkthrough.

I have downloaded the specified version of Node.js, and I have saved the code provided into a sublime file under the name server.js, and stored on the desktop in a folder called njtest.

On the step "Preparing your Environment", I run the cmd prompt and I get the error "The system cannot find the path specific".

Am I missing prompts in my js file and my cmd prompt?

Comment: If you run the exact same commands and have the exact same names the tutorial says it should work. Are you sure that's what you doing? Post an image of the console displaying the error and your commands.

Comment: My command prompt says:

C:\Users\My User> cd njtest node server.js
The system cannot find the path specified

I also try to separate cd njtest from node server.js and run them separately but I get the same error

sorry- would add photos but I am unable to

Comment: You need to run them separately. But you need to run them in your desktop directory.

Comment: How do I go about that? Again, sorry, very new to all of this I am sure this is very basic.

Comment: It's ok. run cd Desktop and then your commands.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! @Jackowski

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the PATH. If you're using Windows go to the start menu and type in Edit the system environment variables. From there go to Environment variables. Then in the system variables section, find where it says PATH and double click it. Click "New" and type in the path (should be whatever you saved it under. Something along the lines of C:\Node.js\bin) Remember that PATH's are case sensitive. If you have any more detailed questions about specifying the path, a quick internet search should yield many answers. Hope this helps!! Good luck and don't give up.